# Test, if a hash key exists and print values of Hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

If a key exists in a array, I want to print that key and its values from hash. Here is the code I wrote.

```
for($i=0;$i<@array.length;$i++)
{
    if (exists $hash{$array[$i]})
    {
        print OUTPUT $array[$i],"\n";
    }
}
```

From the above code, I am able to print keys. But I am not sure how to print values of that key.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@array.length` is syntactically legal, but it's definitely not what you want.

`@array`, in scalar context, gives you the number of elements in the array.

The `length` function, with no argument, gives you the length of `$_`.

The `.` operator performs string concatenation.

So `@array.length` takes the number of elements in `@array` and the length of the string contained in `$_`, treats them as strings, and joins them together.  `$i < ...` imposes a numeric context, so it's likely to be treated as a number -- but surely not the one you want.  (If `@array` has 15 elements and `$_` happens to be 7 characters long, the number should be `157`, a meaningless value.)

The right way to compute the number of elements in `@array` is just `@array` in scalar context -- or, to make it more explicit, `scalar @array`.

To answer your question, if `$array[$i]` is a *key*, the corresponding *value* is `$hash{$array[$i]}`.

But a C-style `for` loop is not the cleanest way to traverse an array, especially if you only need the value, not the index, on each iteration.

```
foreach my $elem (@array) {
    if (exists $hash{$elem}) {
        print OUTPUT "$elem\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `use Array::Utils qw(:all); for(intersect(@array,keys %hash)){print;}`

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative methods using hash slices:

```
foreach (@hash{@array}) { print OUTPUT "$_\n" if defined };

print OUTPUT join("\n",grep {defined} @hash{@array});
```

(For those who like golfing).